# Embedding Advanced Find View in Entity Form (Crm 2011)

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

We making a system so work on a list of records based on 'Fetch XML' the user specify. (Simple FetchXml field)

To make it easy we want to do a nice UI to edit the 'Fetch XML'.

We saw [this](http://crmentropy.blogspot.co.il/2009/03/microsoft-crm-embedding-advanced-find.html) solution - but it is for CRM 4.

Is there anything similar for CRM 2011?

Answer (score 1):

```
// JavaScript source code
function SearchCustomers() {

    var params = '';   

    var fullname = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("fullname").getValue();
    if (fullname != null) {
        params += "fullname" + GetParam(fullname);        
    }    
    var IFrame = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("IFRAME_advancedfind");

    var url = getServerUrl() + "/WebResources/new_advancedfind.htm?Data=" + params;
    IFrame.setSrc(url);
}

function GetParam(data) {
    return "%3D" + encodeURIComponent(data) + "%26";
}
function getServerUrl() {
    //var context = GetGlobalContext();
    //var serverUrl = context.getClientUrl();
    var serverUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + Xrm.Page.context.getOrgUniqueName();
    if (serverUrl.match(/\/$/)) {
        serverUrl = serverUrl.substring(0, serverUrl.length - 1);
    }
    return serverUrl;
}
```

// new_advancedfind.htm Webresource

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE></TITLE>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>    

    function submitForm() {

        var fullname = "";
        var vals = getDataParam();
        fullname = GetParam(vals, 'fullname');

        var filter = '<filter type="and"> <condition attribute="fullname" value="%' + fullname + '%" operator="like"/> <condition attribute="statecode" value="0" operator="eq"/> </filter>';
        var fetch = '<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false"><entity name="contact"><attribute name="fullname"/><attribute name="telephone1"/><attribute name="contactid"/><order attribute="fullname" descending="false"/>' + filter + '</entity></fetch>';
        var form = document.getElementById("AdvancedFind");

        form.action = getServerUrl() + '/AdvancedFind/fetchData.aspx';
        form.LayoutXml.value = '<grid name="resultset" object="2" jump="lastname" select="1" icon="1" preview="1"><row name="result" id="contactid"><cell name="fullname" width="300" /><cell name="telephone1" width="125" /></row></grid>';

        form.FetchXml.value = fetch;
        form.submit();
    }
function getServerUrl() {
    //var context = GetGlobalContext();
    //var serverUrl = context.getClientUrl();
    var serverUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + Xrm.Page.context.getOrgUniqueName();
    if (serverUrl.match(/\/$/)) {
        serverUrl = serverUrl.substring(0, serverUrl.length - 1);
    }
    return serverUrl;
}
function getDataParam() {

    //Get the any query string parameters and load them
    //into the vals array
    var RetVals = new Array();
    var vals = new Array();
    if (location.search != "") {
        vals = location.search.substr(1).split("&");
        for (var prmCounter = 0; prmCounter < vals.length; prmCounter++) {
            vals[prmCounter] = vals[prmCounter].replace(/\+/g, " ").split("=");
        }
        //look for the parameter named 'data'
        var found = false;
        for (var _prmCounter = 0; _prmCounter < vals.length; _prmCounter++) {
            if (vals[_prmCounter][0].toLowerCase() == "data") {
                RetVals = parseDataValue(vals[_prmCounter][1]);
            }
        }

    }
    return RetVals;
}

function parseDataValue(datavalue) {
    if (datavalue != "") {
        return decodeURIComponent(datavalue).split("&");
    }
}
function GetParam(vals, attribute) {
    var val = '';
    var found = false;
    for (i = 0; i < vals.length && !found; i++) {
        if (vals[i].indexOf(attribute) > -1) {
            val = vals[i].split('=')[1];
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return val;
}
</SCRIPT>
<META charset=utf-8></HEAD>
<BODY onload=submitForm()>
<FORM id="AdvancedFind" method="post" action="">
<INPUT name=FetchXml type=hidden> 
<INPUT name=LayoutXml type=hidden> 
<INPUT name=EntityName value=contact type=hidden> 
    <!--Replace DefaultAdvFindViewId valu to contact's default advanced find view Guid-->
<INPUT name=DefaultAdvFindViewId value={00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000000666400} type=hidden> 
<INPUT name=ViewId value={00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000000666400} type=hidden> 
<INPUT name=ViewType value=4230 type=hidden> 
<INPUT name=SortCol value=fullname:1; type=hidden> 
<INPUT name=UIProvider type=hidden> 
<INPUT name=DataProvider type=hidden> </FORM></BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Can you please contact me at Skype: yacov.adzz

Comment: I had to change the ViewType to 1039 for a system view.
<INPUT name="ViewType" value="1039" type="hidden">

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this (yet) but I think it should be possible to do this (in a supported manner) using [URL addressable views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150850.aspx). Somehow create the view in CRM (either manually before time using adv find for example) or create it dynamically with JS. Then it should be possible to "invoke" the view per link above.

Disclaimer: This is all theory. If you get something working maybe let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did on the Dynamics CRM 2011, It's working all deployments, Online/OnPremise and Hosted(IFD),

1. Create a Javascript web-resource, and create your FetchXML then send to Custom advanced Find Web resource.
2. Create a Html web-resource for Showing Advanced Find Grid that execute created dynamic FetchXml for all Entity.

Comment: Can you please give a sample with the web-resources and java-scripts?